# Show that there is a month in which at least $4$ people have a birthday and that there is also a month in which at most $3$ people have a birthday

Tags: combinatorics

Our class has $47$ registered students. Show that there is a month in which at least $4$ people have a birthday and that there is also a month in which at most $3$ people have a birthday.

My attempt: Assume that there is no month in which more than $3$ students have birthdays. Then there are at most $3 \times 12 = 36$ students. This is a contradiction since there are $47$ students. Am I right?

Comment: $12\cdot3<47<12\cdot4$

Comment: Alternatively: the _average_ number of birthdays per month must be $\frac{47}{12} = 3\frac{11}{12}$. The only way an average of integers can be a non-integer is if some of the numbers are more than average and others are less than the average.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is right.

You also need to do the other part: suppose there is **no** month in which at most three people have their birthday. Then **all** months have at least 4 birthdays, so...

Comment: ....thanks for helping